# A question about example of divergent

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

what are the example of for these problems i am trying but not figure it out can any one help please
for first one $\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is this right

Comment: You know how to do the second one. Come on, try something. For the first one, take a big step to the right, then a small step back, then another big step to the right, then a small step back, etc.

Comment: @zhw.yea can you help me i try

Comment: @zhw. Is that the "Time Warp"  .... again?

Comment: @suresh Are the partial sums of the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ increasing for $0<r<1$?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just give you lists of numbers that spring to mind:

5)
1, -1, 2, -1, 3, -1, 4, -1, 5, -1, 6, -1....

The partial sum does not always increase, but the series diverges to infinity.

6) 
$1/1^2$, $1/2^2$, $1/3^2$, $1/4^2$, $1/5^2$, ...

The partial sum for the above increases, but the overall series must diverge to a specific value. (I'll leave that as an exercise :)

Comment: ,,,,,for 5 the partial series 1,2,3......increasing

Answer (score 1):

For the first take the sequence $$x_n=(1,-2,4,-8,16,-32,64,-128....)$$

The partial sums $s_n=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ do not form an increasing sequence.

So this sum has the form $x_1+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}b_n$ where $b_n=x_n+x_{n+1}>0$ for $n>2$

But $x_1+x_2+x_3+.....=x_1+(x_2+x_3)+(x_4+x_5)+(x_6+x_7)+...=+\infty$

For the second take $x_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$